# Unable to load dynamic library php_ldap.dll on linux

Tags: php, ldap

Hi I'm running a Linux server and I keep getting this error thrown as a notice.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_ldap.dll' - 
>    /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_ldap.dll: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Is a `.dll` still needed? I have the .so since it's on linux.

Comment: Edit your php.ini to replace php_ldap.dll to php_ldap.so. And make sure php_ldap.so exist

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install php-ldap` solved it for me